# How do I make a file look as though it was named something else all along in git?

Tags: git, git-history

I have a file named `control.lua` in a git repository, but I would like to make it appear as though it was called `init.lua` all along. How should I approach this?

Comment: You cannot change any existing commits in any way. Each commit is a complete snapshot of all files, so all commits that exist that name the file `control.lua` will name it that way forever. You can copy the repository over to a new, different repository with new, different commits that name it `init.lua`, but you must then get everyone to switch to your new, different repository with new, different commits. If that's worth doing, look into using `git filter-branch` to do the copying—it works in-place, but the effect is a new, different repository.

Comment: Alternatively, leave the file with the old name in all the existing commits, and make all new commits from now on use the new name. Git itself does not care what the name is; Git just stores content.

Comment: You can absolutely do this but only if you delete the entire git history (delete .git and run git init again).

Comment: So what you're *really* asking is how to bypass the entire source code control concept? Just `git mv` it and get on with your life :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo I am in the process of splitting one-file libraries out of a big repository into their own repositories where they can be used many projects as subtrees; however, this means that if I have a file like `math.lua`, then in order to make it its own repository, I must put it into a folder. It makes sense then to move this file to `math/math.lua`; however, this kind of naming convention is strange. Instead, I would like it to be moved to `math/init.lua` since `init` is a common name for the root file of a library.

Comment: So that would be `git mv math.lua math/init.lua`, yes? Or, if you're creating a brand new repo, just put them in with their new names from the get-go. I'm still not sure why you need to *backdate* changes, perhaps I'm not seeing the full picture.

Comment: @paxdiablo They are being split out of a large central git repository into their *own* git repositories. git equips you with the tools to break up a repository, but not with the tools to rename these files to make more sense in their new repositories.